# SQL Server Consuming Most of the CPU Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-administration

In my environment CPU utilization is high in a particular timezone. When i ran the below query i got to know that the sql server so and so record id consuming the most of the CPU time.

```
DECLARE @ms_ticks_now BIGINT
SELECT @ms_ticks_now = ms_ticks
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;
SELECT  record_id
       ,dateadd(ms, - 1 * (@ms_ticks_now - [timestamp]), GetDate()) AS EventTime
       ,SQLProcessUtilization
       ,SystemIdle
       ,100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS OtherProcessUtilization
       ,TIMESTAMP
FROM (
       SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id
              ,record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS SystemIdle
              ,record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 'int') AS SQLProcessUtilization
              ,TIMESTAMP
       FROM (
              SELECT TIMESTAMP
                     ,convert(XML, record) AS record
              FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
              WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'
                     AND record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%'
              ) AS x
       ) AS y
ORDER BY record_id DESC
```

using the `RecordID` from obtained result,  Can we get the query text which was ran . If we can please share the query

Thanks 
Rama Raju

Comment: what you meant by particular timezone, u mean on specific times

Comment: TimeZone is Nothing but out application busy business hours.Above query results timestamp... For that particular time stamp which query was ran

Answer (score 0):

I use the below query to find queries and see the plans for the top 100 AvgDuration, or you can modify to order by TotalCPU. As long as plan cache has not been flushed, you should be able to find queries and last_execution_time. Pretty sure I found this query somewhere on StackOverflow, can't remember exactly where though.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    DB_NAME(st.dbid) as DatabaseName,
    total_worker_time / execution_count AS AvgCPU ,
    total_worker_time AS TotalCPU ,
    (total_elapsed_time / execution_count)/1000000 AS AvgDurationSeconds,
    total_elapsed_time AS TotalDuration ,
    total_elapsed_time / 1000000 as TotalDurationSeconds,
    total_logical_reads / execution_count AS AvgReads ,
    total_logical_reads AS TotalReads ,
    execution_count ,
    qs.creation_time AS plan_creation_time,
    qs.last_execution_time,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(st.text, ( qs.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1, ( ( CASE qs.statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
        END - qs.statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1),CHAR(13), ''),CHAR(9),' '),CHAR(10),' ')) AS QueryText,
        query_plan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
    WHERE DB_NAME(st.dbid) IS NOT NULL
    /* Sorting options - uncomment the one you'd like to use: */
    --ORDER BY TotalReads DESC;
    --ORDER BY TotalCPU DESC;
    ORDER BY AvgDurationSeconds DESC;
    --ORDER BY TotalDuration DESC;
    --ORDER BY execution_count DESC;
```